# Show/Hide Image DIV

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide

I want the image to act as a toggle so when it's clicked on it will reveal the div with the text.

Here's the CSS class I'm using:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
.unhidden { display: block; }
```

and the JS:

```
 function unhide(divID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
  }
}//
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="4u">                    
   <!-- Box -->
   <section class="box box-feature">
      <a href="javascript:unhide('test');" class="image image-full" 
      <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" /></a>
   <div id="test" class="hidden">
       <header>
       <h2>Put something here</h2>
       <span class="byline">Maybe here as well I think</span>
       </header>
<p>Test and more text and more text and more text.</p>
    </div>                          
   </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/LeUAZ/2/

Comment: What happens when you run it? If you pasted the code as is, there will be an issue because you don't have the `>` on you anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error. Change line 4 to:

```
  <a href="javascript:unhide('test');" class="image image-full">
```

Note the `>` at the end of the line.

Unless you're determined to use vanilla JavaScript, a much easier way would be to use jQuery. Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And then your `a href` could be just `javascript:$('#test').toggle()` and you wouldn't need to define any functions or CSS classes.